# How to count clicks of random images?

Tags: javascript, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to make a random sequence triggered by mouse click, and track how many times a user would click on the images. Could anyone help me with that? Thanks!
Below are my code that are pulling images randomly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Door Moment</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function changePic()
        {
            var num = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9);
            document.getElementById("p").src =  num + ".jpg";
        }
        function buttonclick() {
            document.getElementById("p").value++;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p align="center"><img src = "1.jpg" id = "p" width="400px" height="600px" onclick="changePic()" /></p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: how long a user would click on the images? do you mean how many times a user will click on the same image?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. Yes I mean how many times a user will click on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you start your image sequence from 1, you can use a counter to count your image click times.

When image element is clicked, buttonclick function will track how many times user has clicked on the image. And then change your current image sequence number which will show a different image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Door Moment</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        const counter = {};
        let num = 1;
        

        function changePic()
        {
            num = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9);
            document.getElementById("p").src =  num + ".jpg";
        }
        function buttonclick() {
            counter[num] = (counter[num] || 0) + 1;
            console.log(counter)
            //if you want to show current count for the sequence, you can use     console.log(counter[num])
            changePic()
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p align="center"><img src = "1.jpg" id = "p" width="400px" height="600px" onclick="buttonclick()" /></p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try make `clickCounter` object with a key equal to the picture number and better use `onclick`method in JS but not in html

```js
let num = 1;
const clickCounter = {};
const randomPic = document.getElementById('randomPic')

randomPic.onclick = function(){
    clickCounter[num] = (clickCounter[num] || 0) + 1;
    changePic();
    console.log(clickCounter); // if you need  
}

function changePic() {
    num = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9);
    randomPic.src = num + ".jpg";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Door Moment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p align="center"><img src = "1.jpg" id = "randomPic" width="400px" height="600px"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```